# Matching all strings without 3 occurrences of/or final single character in RegEx

Tags: regex

Trying to figure out the regex for the title,

i.e.,

1. foo
2. foo/bar/foo
3. foo/bar/foo/bar
4. foo/bar/d

I don't want it to match the 3rd or the 4th one but match the first two. In the 2nd option, the final foo can be anything but a single d.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using regex for this? I feel like it would be simpler without

Comment: It's to be used in a web config to match variable urls and redirect.

Comment: it's a .net web config, matches existing urls and redirects them if the string matches.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: This is not a drive-thru regex stand. What effort have you made yourself to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex but it will be more complicated than just counting the number of slashes and also checking the last character isn't a d. If you want to use a regex to check for the last part not being "/d" you could do something like check that it doesn't match ^.*/d$ but it may be clearer to just use code. (If counting slashes and checking string doesn't end in "/d" isn't exactly what you mean then it will help to have more examples)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. See below if anyone is interested.

```
(^foo/?$)|(^foo/[^/]+/(([^d][^/]*)|(d[^/]+))/?$)
```

Comment: How sure are you that this is exactly correct? How friendly is it for somebody maintaining this code?